# Robust shared memory mutex

Tags: c++

I plan to use shared memory mutex for IPC. How can I avoid the dead lock condition when one of the processes dies unexpectedly before releasing the mutex?

I know one of the solutions is to make the mutex robust. However, there is a glibc bug where the mutex can randomly hung (see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1302389#c2). It looks like this issue was not fixed in the glibc I am using. Even it is fixed in a newer version, I don't have the freedom to upgrade glibc library.

Is there any workaround for the issue or are there any alternative solutions?

Thanks

Comment: The alternative solution is to use resources which the OS will cleanup if your program terminates, such as file locks.

Comment: Thanks. How can I detect or recover from the condition using file lock? Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: If a process that holds a lock on a file terminates, the lock always get automatically released.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sysv ipc semaphores, which normally undo all the semaphore operations you do in case you process dies. there's a per process counter on each semaphore that accounts the net balance of P and V operations done on it, so in case the process dies, it can adjust the semaphore accordingly when it dies (being due to a signal or through the `exit(2)` call)

It has the drawback of consuming a resource per semaphore and process, although.  But they are included in all unix variants nowadays, so you'll be portable to other systems.